# How to make a MKMapView come in from the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I have a normal MKMap view with a basic MKAnnoation what i want to accomplish is that my annotation is in the UK and the MKCoordinateSpan is 0.05 but i want the MKMapView start from a view of the whole UK and zoom in to the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    /* set here the region from where map will be zooming; */
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld) animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    /* set here your end point of zooming */
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;

    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:zoomLocation animated:YES];
    CLLocationDistance locationDistance = [self locationDistance:0.5];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, locationDistance, locationDistance);
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}

- (CLLocationDistance )locationDistance:(CGFloat )value {
    return 1609.344 *value;
}
```